# AngularJS toggle from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS showhide here http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/ this is what I have:

```
<div ui-toggle="showHide">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                  <input class="form-control" id="id_password" name="password"
                     type="password"  ng-model="password" placeholder="Password">
               </div>
            </div>


<p><a ng-click="showHide=!showHide">Toggle State: {{!!showHide}}</a></p>
```

This works however, how can I control the toggle directly from a controller?

Comment: You can set `showHide` in your controller: `$scope.showHide = !$scope.showHide;`  Although I'd just use the `ng-show` and `ng-hide` directives.

Comment: could I see an example of the ng-show and ng-hide directives and how to use them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a fiddle showing the use of `ng-show` and `ng-hide`

http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/WUc94/

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrlr',['$scope',function($scope){
   $scope.show = true;

   $scope.toggle = function(){
      $scope.show = !$scope.show;
   };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrlr">
        <div ng-show="show">I'm using ngShow!!!</div>
        <div ng-hide="show">I'm using ngHide!!!</div>
        <div>Value of "show": <strong>{{show}}</strong></div>
        <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could just as easily use one of the directives too:

```
<div ng-show="show">I'm using ngShow (show == true)</div>
<div ng-show="!show">I'm using ngShow (show == false)</div>
```